# Vue.js nullish coalescing operator (??) error in v-calendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, babeljs

I am getting this error:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. [sic]

#### The full error

```
error  in ./node_modules/v-calendar/dist/es/index.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1889:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const resolveEl = (target) => {
|   if (target == null)
>     return target ?? null;
|   if (document && isString_1(target))
|     return document.querySelector(target);

 @ ./src/main.js 13:0-35 15:0-65 27:12-21 29:12-25 30:30-38 31:32-42
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.88.134:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

#### My *babel.config.js* file

```javascript
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
  ],
};
```

#### My *vue.config.js* file

```javascript
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ["@gtm-support/vue-gtm", "v-calendar"],
  productionSourceMap: false,
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      config.output
        .filename("[name].[hash].js")
        .chunkFilename("[name].[hash].js")
        .end();
    }
  },
```

I have installed the necessary plugins with this command:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

But it is still not working.

Comment: Probably the setup (vue loader) needs to be updated any way

Comment: The use of `??` in `if (target == null) return target ?? null` doesn't make sense. `== null` already ensures that `target` can only be either `null` or `undefined`, so `return target ?? null` can be simplified as `return null`.

Comment: @InSync it's not OP's code, the error comes from the **compiled** code of the v-calendar library: `./node_modules/v-calendar/dist/es/index.js`

Comment: Possibly the issue is resolved with simple `vue upgrade` command.  Otherwise, try the [solution](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/issues/1271#issuecomment-1499152262) reported on the v-calendar github

Comment: Thanks @yoduh , the project runs but with lots of warnings which wasn't the case before. The main problem now is that when I go to the page where I have integrated v-calendar I get three runtime errors.
1. dates.push is not a function
2. _ctx.pages[0] is undefined
3. node is null
Earlier everything was working fine (1-2 months ago)